# ClassNotFoundException on GAE with GWT RPC

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc, playn

I'm using PlayN to develop a game. It contains a type,`GameEvent`, defined in `my-game-core` project. My GWT and GAE code lives in `my-game-html`, which has `my-game-core` as a Maven dependency.

Here is the service impl:

```
package com.mygame.html.server;

import com.mygame.core.event.GameEvent;
import com.mygame.html.client.ServerEventHandlerService;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ServerEventHandlerServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet
        implements ServerEventHandlerService {

    @Override
    public String handleEvent(final GameEvent event) {
        return "holy porkchops batman!";
    }

}
```

This compiles just fine. However, when I try to call the service at runtime on the local dev server, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mygame/core/event/GameEvent
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mygame.core.event.GameEvent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
```

If I take out `GameEvent` and replace it with a type like `String`, everything works fine.

What could I be doing wrong here? `GameEvent` has a default constructor.

**Update**: Here is pom.xml for the *-html project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>mygame-game</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mygame</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>mygame-game-html</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>my game html build</name>

  <properties>
    <gwt.module>com.mygame.MygameGame</gwt.module>
    <gwt.name>mygame</gwt.name>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mygame</groupId>
      <artifactId>mygame-game-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.playn</groupId>
        <artifactId>playn-html</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- we need class metadata, override PlayN's disabling of such -->
        <configuration>
          <disableClassMetadata>false</disableClassMetadata>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
          <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildCommand>
              <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
            </buildCommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Update 2**: In `war/WEB-INF/lib`, I have:

- appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.4.jar
- appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.5.jar
- appengine-api-labs-1.5.4.jar
- appengine-api-labs-1.5.5.jar
- appengine-jsr107cache-1.5.4.jar
- appengine-jsr107cache-1.5.5.jar
- datanucleus-appengine-1.0.9.final.jar
- datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
- datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
- geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
- geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
- gwt-servlet.jar
- jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
- jsr107cache-1.1.jar

Comment: Are you using Maven to build the GAE war file? If so, the `pom.xml` file may be relevant here. It definitely sounds like Maven is not putting your `my-game-core` dependency in the right place (which is `WEB-INF/lib`). If you open up the war file in an archive viewer, what are the contents of `war/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: What is the war file? I have a war directory. I added pom.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing your dependency my-game-core in the runtime classpath of the jetty that gwt launches.

Did you import your project with mvn eclipse:eclipse into eclipse?
Maybe your runtime classpath still points to your local maven repo, but you already changed your eclipse project (my-game-core). Take a look at your eclipse classpath and make sure it only has the other project on it and not the jar from the repo.

Also check on the classpath tab in your run configuration.

Comment: Where can I change my runtime classpath? I went to the run configuration >> classpath tab and added the *-core project, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: this is your runtimeclasspath... also take a look at your war directory. What libs do you have under WEB-INF/lib

Comment: See http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_with_maven Your `my-game-core.jar` must be in the `WEB-INF/lib`.